# Actualizar clientes automáticamente desde servidor privado

Tags: windows, activedirectory

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada, la cual quiero publicar desde un servidor privado, es decir, solo se puede acceder a el desde la corporación, mi desarrollo ha sido realizado desde fuera y la única manera que tengo de introducir es mediante la publicación en un USB y pasarlo dentro.

Es la primera vez que me enfrento a las actualizaciones automáticas y no tengo ni idea de cómo afrontarlas, supongo que en los clientes debe haber algún lanzador que consulte al servidor y obtener la versión.

El servidor es un **Windows Server 2016 Standard** y mi pregunta es:

#### ¿Existe una herramienta interna para actualizaciones automáticas de aplicaciones propias?

Y si la respuesta es afirmativa:

#### ¿Cómo puedo usarla y configurar los clientes?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esa herramienta no existe, estamos hablando de un amplio espectro de situaciones tales como los distintos sistemas operativos existentes.

Hace unos años trabajé con una aplicación que hacía eso y bueno la verdad no es la gran cosa, en cuanto a la lógica de la acción, la aplicación cliente cada vez que se inicia debe consultar a un repositorio en el servidor si es que hay una nueva versión del mismo software, y bueno ahí debes determinar cuales son los archivos que vas a actualizar, mediante las opciones que te permita el cliente y dependiendo del sistema operativo deberás hacer algunas acciones como registrar los nuevos archivos y dll's en el caso de Windows, ahora si el desarrollo anterior no hace una actualización automática según el esquema que te describo, deberás hacerlo e instalar manualmente en cada maquina cliente la primera vez, luego como ya desarrollaste la actualización automática podrás actualizar los archivos en el repositorio en tu server y con eso ya bastaría, este repositorio puede ser un FTP o una carpeta compartida de un equipo servidor, el tema aquí no es que Windows Server usas si no, la manera en que implementaras tu actualización automática.

saludos